# Google Maps in Chrome ARC

Tags: android, maps, google-chrome-arc

I recently saw that ARC is now supporting a few Google Play Services including Google Maps.

When using the ARC Welder, I specify the following metadata:

```
{"usePlayServices":["maps"]}
```

According to the documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/arc_playservices), I must also include the crx_key value in the metadata. When doing so, the additional metadata appears as such:

```
{
 "usePlayServices":["maps"],
 "crx_key":"<KEY FROM WEBSTORE>"
}
```

Attempting to Launch the App causes an "Error Loading Extension" message:

[image: Error Message]

Any ideas as to why I'm receiving this error? I made sure the key has no white spaces/line returns as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When copying your public key from the web store, it's important to select exactly the right thing.  The highlighted portion below is the public key, make sure not to select the `-----BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY-----` annotations, and to remove any line breaks / whitespace (as you said you already had).

[image: The public key here is MIIB...QAB]

Comment: Thanks for your response @Elijah Taylor. Unfortunately I had already copied the key between the -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY------ and -----END PUBLIC KEY----- text as it was also mentioned in the documentation

Comment: All I can suggest is try again.  I just used this metadata to yield ID hpkfkbodpaljnnjnflbgefgphkkbpkco.  Maybe you can try with this: 
(crud, copying from stackoverflow includes line breaks, here's a pastebin for it: http://pastebin.com/n3By2t8E )

Comment: When copying your key from pastebin, the application launched without the error. I used online tools to remove line breaks and white spaces and it fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This Additional Metadata worked for my apk that uses Google Maps API for Android and Google Location API:

```
{
  "usePlayServices": ["location", "maps"]
}
```