# Geolocation in ARC Welder on OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome-arc

How can one give an app access to geolocation information when running from ARC Welder on OSX? I'm assuming it should be added in *metadata* before launching.

Comment: See my answer to this question:
[Google Maps in Chrome ARC][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433981/google-maps-in-chrome-arc?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to get the *public key* as I'm trying to run an existing app, not a project of my own.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your APK declares any location permission (e.g. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), ARC Welder adds geolocation permission for you.