# Getting location with Android app on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

I'm in the process of getting our Android app running under Chrome using ARC Welder.  One of the things we do is get the user's location.  This works fine under Android, but not under Chrome.  We never get notified that a location is available.

The bottom of this page indicates that location services should work:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc

I've added the following to the arc_metadata

```
"usePlayServices": [
  "location"
],
```

Although I don't see why it is needed I've also added the Oauth 2 token to the ARC Welder window.

I'm still not getting a location returned.  Does anyone know the secret sauce?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps in Chrome ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433981/google-maps-in-chrome-arc)